# Swift - Resizing image quality on Device and Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

In my app I have several icon's 44x44 which are images (png's) I have created in Sketch.

Now when I add then images and run the app on the simulator the image is displayed nicely and the quality is good on all devices. Here is a picture of it on the Simulator:

[image: [enter image description here]

But when I run the app on a real device (the same device as I run it on the simulator) I get this badly quality image:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Could anyone explain why this happens please?

I am currently using this pod and editing it a little, Plus the Pod is in Obj C so I do not fully understand it all...

The button's I have the icon is a toolBar as you'll be able to see from this link:

[Link to the pod](https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-Editor-iOS)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 44x44 pixels or points? I suspect pixels. In this case, create it in 44*3 x 44*3 pixels. [This might also be helpful](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/image-size-and-resolution/)

Comment: @shallowThought yes pixels, I have 3 images for each icon. First icon is 44 second is 2x and third is 3x. Thanks I'll check the link out

Comment: Than I am wrong. Sorry.

Comment: Maybe post some code how you use the images (Tabbar icon, UIImage...)

Comment: @shallowThought Well I am actually using the pod example here https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-Editor-iOS, and its the tool bar for the keyboard

Comment: [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41199825/edit) your question to get more/better/faster answers.

Comment: @shallowThought Thanks for the advice, I'll try

Comment: How did you export it from Sketch? 1x, 2x, or 3x? Have you tried to import it into your Xcode app assets?

Comment: @dfd ib both 3 modes, I have imported 3 images 44px 88px 132px